# Computing the Dehn Invariant for a cube (Numberphile)

Tags: tensors, polyhedra

In [this video](https://youtu.be/eYfpSAxGakI?t=781) by Numberphile, the Dehn invariant is computed by noting that there are 12 edges all having dihedral angle $\frac{\pi}{2}$

We compute the invariant using linearity in first slow

$$ 1 \otimes \frac{\pi}{2} + 1 \otimes \frac{\pi}{2} ... \text{12 times} = 12 \otimes \frac{\pi}{2 } \tag{1}$$

But, suppose we had added things in the second slot, and then use the fact that the second slot is mod $2\pi$:

$$  1 \otimes \frac{\pi}{2} + 1 \otimes \frac{\pi}{2} ... \text{12 times} = 1 \otimes (12 \frac{\pi}{2}) = 1 \otimes 6 \pi = 1 \otimes 0 \tag{2}$$

How would I show (1)=(2)?

Comment: General advice : Avoid math online videos.

Comment: Dehn invariants live in $\mathbb{R}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{R}/2\pi \mathbb{Z}$, and by definition (one defintion of the tensor product, anyway), $(na)\otimes b = a\otimes (nb)$ for any $n\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How you’d show that depends on your definition of the tensor product. Under [the definition of the tensor product as a quotient module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_modules#Construction), the tensors $(na)\otimes b$ and $a\otimes(nb)$ are equivalent by definition.